# has only ever been captured once before?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

In the following sentence, should "has only ever been" be re-written as "was only ever"? That portion of the sentence describes an event prior to the more recent one of more than 100 whales being filmed off the coast of Australia.

> A “megapod” of more than 100 humpback whales has been filmed surrounding a boat off the coast of Australia ─ an incredibly rare event an expert says **has only ever been** captured once before in the country’s waters.

Comment: Good as is. Present perfect is often used for describing an event that occurred at some indeterminate time in the past.

Comment: Have you noticed there are two present perfects in the OP sentence?

Comment: I hadn't specifically noticed that, but it doesn't change the answer.

Comment: Is there a contradiction in the following sentences? Can both be valid at the same time?

a. John has only ever seen unicorns once before.
b. John has seen unicorns twice in his life so far.

Comment: Contradiction! They would mean the same thing if you had written either "once" or "twice" in both sentences.

Comment: Yes, and I reckon the same situation holds in the OP sentence.  The OP sentence (along with information further down in the source article) entails that Australians have seen megapods of humpback whales off the coast of Australia **twice**.   Moreover, the part, "an incredibly rare event an expert says has only ever been captured once before in the country’s waters" means Australians have seen a megapod of humpback whales swimming off the coast of Australia **only once before.**

Comment: In other words, we obtain from the situation described the following two sentences: a. Australians have seen a megapod of humback whales swimming off the coast of Australia **twice.**
b. Australians have seen a megapod of humpback whales swimming off the coast of Australia **only once before**.

Comment: Ok I just deleted my comment stating that "had been" would be best. Let me think.

Comment: @cruthers Thank you for discussing this matter with me. As a non-native speaker, I often see issues like this, but native speakers tend to dismiss them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a deceptively tricky question. Here is my reaction, now that it is clear that the confusion stems from the double use of the present perfect. The short answer is that the original sentence is fine, and I'm not sure that it can be improved through any other combination of past simple, present perfect, or past perfect.

The order of events is super clear in this sentence:

> 1. A megapod was filmed yesterday, an event that had only been captured once before.

We have an event here in the first clause at a definite point in the past, indicated by the past simple, and then the past perfect is used in the second clause to indicate the time before this event.  Works great.  Now consider this sentence:

> 2. A megapod was filmed, an event that had only been captured once before.

This is also grammatically correct, but it wouldn't be idiomatic for an article to start describing an event using the simple past ("a megapod was filmed") without indicating at all when it occurred. The idiomatic way to express that something occurred recently in this context, without stating exactly when, is to use the present perfect, which is what the author did. Therefore, the author had three options:

> 3. A megapod has been filmed, an event that has only been captured once before.
> 4. A megapod has been filmed, an event that had only been captured once before.
> 5. A megapod has been filmed, an event that was only captured once before.

In my opinion, all three sentences make sense, but they are written in order of decreasing idiomaticness (if that's a word). Sentence 3 is good; sentence 4 is acceptable; sentence 5 sounds bad to me. I understand how it is tempting to want the grammar to reflect the order of events, as is the case in sentence 1 with the simple past. However, in my opinion (and I'd be curious to see whether others agree - it's easy to overthink this), this loses something stylistically. Note that context makes the order clear in any event (when I first read the sentence, I couldn't even identify the issue), so the only question is which choice sounds most natural.

It's important to understand that, while the present perfect is used to indicate that something happened within a time frame that extends to the present, the length of the time frame is highly context-dependent. In the first clause of sentence 3, the time frame begins some time in the ambiguously recent past; the time frame in the second clause begins at the creation of the universe.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the time frame for "Australians have only seen a megapod of whales swimming off the coast of Australia **once**" is the time that begins at the creation of the universe and extends to the time of speech (or writing). But that still contradicts what the first clause of the OP sentence implies, i.e., the fact that Australians have seen that sort of megapod off the coast of Australia **twice**.

Comment: Think of the "before" as an additional condition. They've only seen it once *before* the recent sighting. It might not be perfectly satisfying, but it is idiomatic and therefore perhaps creates a dissonance that we need to tolerate!

Comment: I'm not sure whether the present perfect in your "They've only seen it once before the recent sighting" conforms to rules about the present perfect.  We might restore "before the recent sighting" to a clause to see the tense relations more clearly. Consider "before they made the recent sighting in the same waters." If so, then the following two alternatives make more sense to me:

Comment: a. Australians **had only seen** a megapod of humpback whales swimming off the coast of Australia **once** before the recent sighting.

b. Australians **only saw** a megapod of humpback whales swimming off the coast of Australia **once** before the recent sighting.

Comment: Yeah, your alternatives are fine, but so is the original. Unfortunately it's not about what makes the most sense; you can't always reason these things out. At this point I can tell that you speak the language well enough to forget about "rules" and instead just focus on how people speak it in practice.

Comment: Actually, I like (a) much more than (b). I also think "only" should probably get moved back so that it is in front of the "once."

Comment: I've found a way to make sense of the OP sentence and resolve the apparent contradiction. The key is that the present perfect can be used to describe a state or event that has been completed and that no longer continues. Another use is to describe accumulation of experience.

Comment: So, "an incredibly rare event an expert says has only ever been captured once before in the country’s waters" is an example of the completion use (so that the "only once" assessment no longer holds), whereas "Australians have seen a megapod off the coast of Australia twice" is an instance of the experiential use.

Comment: The distinction is a bit cryptic for me; not sure I follow. For me, the word “before“ is what makes things clear. Without that word, I might think that there’s only been one sighting.

Comment: The completion sense is illustrated by "The postman has been here," which indicates the postman is no longer here.

Comment: Hmm, but both “seen” and “captured” in the author’s sentence represent complete events from the past; the sighting is not ongoing in either case.

Comment: I think the completion use of the present perfect can be used not only with telic predicates like "see" and "capture," but also with atelic ones. For example, "be here" as in "The postman has been here" is an atelic predicate, but it combines with the completion present perfect well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for past tense.  Past tense would not indicate a sequence of events.

> I have seen Mount Fuji, and my brother saw it yesterday.

This does not mean that you saw Fuji more recently than your brother.

> I have seen Mount Fuji, and my brother saw it too.

This suggests that the time that your brother saw it is determined to be the same time that you saw Fuji, ie that that you saw it together

> I have seen Mt Fuji, and my brother has seen it.

This suggests that you have both seen Mt Fuji but at different times.

> I have seen Mt Fuji, but it has been seen before.

This means that someone has seen Mt Fuji before you did. THe word before indicates sequence. A tense change is not required.

It would be natural to use past perfect if the first clause was in the past tense:

> I saw Mt Fuji yesterday, but my brother had seen it already.

Answer (score 0):

No specific time is mentioned, but the fact that it occurred only once implies a particular time. Thus, either version is acceptable.

Consider this question: "Have you ever been to Mexico?" The answer could be:

> Yes, I've been there once / twice / etc.

Or:

> Yes, I was there once / twice / etc.

I think that "twice" sounds better with the perfect aspect (because the time seems vaguer) and "once" sounds better with the simple form (because the time seems more definite), but either version is acceptable.

Comment: The real issue is, there are two present perfects in the sentence, and the sequence of events is not made explicit.

Comment: If there were only one present perfect, then I'd agree with your answer.

Comment: What do you mean "the sequence of events is not made explicit"? I thought you said in your question that the second event happened before the first, and the phrase "once before" seems to confirm that.

Comment: If you're concerned about that, then the past perfect would also be correct: ". . . an expert says had only ever been captured once before . . ."

Comment: The sentence describes two events, with one happening before the other. Shouldn't the tenses reflect this sequence?

Comment: Not necessarily. I could say, "I've been to Mexico three times, and I've visited Italy twice." The order of events doesn't always need to be explicit.

Comment: Your example is different in that it describes two independent events with no temporal order holding between them.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you're saying. People often say, "I visited Italy last year after I visited Mexico." According to some rules, you should instead use the past perfect for the earlier event: "I visited Italy last year after I had visited Mexico." However, in this case I probably wouldn't be too strict about that particular rule.

Comment: Also, the present tense is often used to describe events that are true in general and not only at one particular time, so you might be able to justify the present perfect (". . . has only ever been captured once before . . .") on those grounds. (For example: "He told me that the Earth has [not "had"!] always revolved around the Sun.")

Comment: It is the present simple tense that is used to describe timeless events. That's not applicable In the OP sentence,

Comment: It is well known that after-clauses do not need the past perfect to reflect order because the conjunction itself establishes the order.